# Unable to install numpy for python 3.6.5

Tags: numpy, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to install numpy with the command `pip3 install numpy`
But I get the following error:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/d5/4f8410ac303e690144f0a0603c4b8fd3b986feb2749c435f7cdbb288f17e/numpy-1.16.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.16.2.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

It says `permission denied` so I ran it with `sudo` and it installed properly.

However when I use any script which uses numpy as `python3 abc.py` I get an error saying no module named numpy. It works well with sudo

How do I install numpy to be used without sudo?

I am running python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Using `sudo` to install python packages will probably install the package in the wrong version of python since the python version in `PATH` can be different for root. Try figuring out what version of python 3 is in your `PATH` when you call it with `which python3` and `which pip3` and use the full path when using `sudo`. e.g. (`sudo /path/to/pip3 install numpy`).

Comment: For python3 the path is /usr/local/bin/python3
And for pip3 the path is /usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: Then you can install numpy to your version of python using `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install numpy`.

Comment: Now it says requirement already satisfied

Comment: Please, verify where your root `python3` executable is with `sudo which python3` and try `/path/to/python3 -c "import numpy"`

Comment: `sudo which python3` also gives /usr/local/bin and running the command `/path/to/python3 -c "import numpy"` gives a module not found error